# SimpleDateFormat returns wrong date in java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

```java
private String dateFormatter(String olddate) {
   String newDate = "";
   try {
       SimpleDateFormat initDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy - HH:mm");
       SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy - HH:mm");
       newDate = formatter.format(initDate.parse(olddate));
   } catch (ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return newDate;
}
```

Input Date is : `29-Mar-22 - 22:00`
Required Output Date is : `29/03/22 - 22:00`

Instead of this I will get parse exception
When I convert current date in **`dd-MMM-yy - HH:mm`**  format it returns 29-M03-22 - 11:38 Which is wrong.

So please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stop using outdated classes. Like SimpleDateFormat. Use the modern java.time API.

Comment: Your code is working - tested on java 8 and java 17, if possible can you post your complete code. Which packages you are importing?

Comment: If you're getting `29-M03-22 - 11:38`, that suggests that the first `M` is not the expected character.  Did you type the M from a Cyrillic or Greek keyboard perhaps, so that it's not a normal ASCII M?

Comment: Which is your default locale? Which is your Java version?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure your formatting pattern is using the letter `M` from the US-ASCII range of Unicode, as [commented by Dawood ibn Kareem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71686726/simpledateformat-returns-wrong-date-in-java/71687842#comment126692806_71686726).

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

```
LocalDateTime
.parse(
    "29-Mar-22 - 22:00" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uu - HH:mm" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) 
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uu - HH:mm" )
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/YM2aLP).

> 29/03/22 - 22:00

---

Tip: Use four digit years. In my experience, saving two digits of space is not worth the confusion caused by the ambiguity.

Tip: Rather than hard-code such formats, (a) use only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for data exchange, and (b) let *java.time* automatically localize when producing string values for presentation to the user.

```java
LocalDateTime
        .parse(
            "29-Mar-22 - 22:00" ,
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uu - HH:mm" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) 
        )
        .format(
            DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.SHORT )
            .withLocale( new Locale( "es" , "AR ") )  // Spanish language, Argentina culture.
        )
```

> 29/3/22 22:00